# User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier) - NullReferenceException from Angular but OK in Postman?

Tags: c#, asp.net, angular, typescript

I am trying to debug a `NullReferenceException` in a .NET Core API and Angular application and I'm out of ideas.

I am trying to update a property of a `User` (the "About" section)

[Update text area screengrab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XHDRc.png)

In the backend code, in `AuthController`, I have a Login method that creates the claims and it seems to work fine:

```
[HttpPost("login")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel loginViewModel)
{
        // login the user
        var userFromRepo = await _authRepository.Login(loginViewModel.Email.ToLower(), loginViewModel.Password);

        // check that user is logged in
        if (userFromRepo == null)
            return Unauthorized();

        // create claims using user id and main email
        var claims = new[]
        {
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, userFromRepo.Id),
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, userFromRepo.MainEmail),
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, userFromRepo.FirstName)
        };

        // generate key from secret token
        var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_config.GetSection("AppSettings:Token").Value));

        // generate hash and credentials
        var cred = new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha512Signature);

        // create token descriptions
        var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
        {
            Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(claims),
            Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1),
            SigningCredentials = cred
        };

        // instantiate token handler
        var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();

        // create token
        var token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);

        // write token and return request
        return Ok(new
        {
            token = tokenHandler.WriteToken(token),
        });
}
```

I then have a method that updates a property of a User:

```
[HttpPut("{id}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateUser(string id, UserForUpdateDto userForUpdateDto)
{
    // this is a check if user ID that is updating the profile matches the ID in the token
    if (id != User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value) 
    {
        return Unauthorized();
    }

    var userFromRepo = await _doMoreRepo.GetUser(id);
    userFromRepo.About = userForUpdateDto.About;
    await _doMoreRepo.UpdateUser(id);
    return NoContent();
}
```

During debugging I get an 500 error with a message

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

on the line of code:

```
User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value
```

It works OK in Postman so my guess is that somehow I am not getting anything from the `NameIdentifier` but I don't know why?

I'm just not sure where to look any more.

My front end Angular code is as follows - `Login` method that adds the token to the storage:

```
login(model: any) {
  return this.http.post(this.url + 'login', model)
  .pipe(
    map((response: any) => {
      const user = response;
      if (user) {
        localStorage.setItem('token', user.token);
        this.decodedToken = this.jwtHelper.decodeToken(user.token);
        console.log('This is decoded token');
        console.log(this.decodedToken);
      }
    })
  );
}
```

Update Profile method:

```
updateProfile() {
    this.userService.updateUser(this.authService.decodedToken.nameid, this.user).subscribe(next => {
      this.alertify.success('Profile updated');
      this.editForm.reset(this.user);
    }, error => {
      console.log(error);
      this.alertify.error(error);
    });
}
```

I looked at very similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59202569/user-findfirstclaimtypes-nameidentifier-doesnt-retrieve-anything-when-called) so I double checked the solution but in my case I do have the `tokenGetter()` included in my `app.module.ts`

```
export function tokenGetter() {
   return localStorage.getItem('token');
}
```

and the import:

```
 JwtModule.forRoot({
     config: {
        tokenGetter,
     }
  })
```

To investigate it more and to make sure that I have narrowed down to possible problem area, in my Controller when I replace the:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateUser(string id, UserForUpdateDto userForUpdateDto)
{
    // this is a check if user ID that is updating the profile matches the ID in the token
    if (id != User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value) 
    {
        return Unauthorized();
    }

    var userFromRepo = await _doMoreRepo.GetUser(id);
    userFromRepo.About = userForUpdateDto.About;
    await _doMoreRepo.UpdateUser(id);
    return NoContent();
}
```

with actual value like this:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateUser(string id, UserForUpdateDto userForUpdateDto)
{
    if (id != "user ID value") 
    {
        return Unauthorized();
    }

    var userFromRepo = await _doMoreRepo.GetUser(id);
    userFromRepo.About = userForUpdateDto.About;
    await _doMoreRepo.UpdateUser(id);
    return NoContent();
}
```

This works ok without any errors and the property is updated ok.

What am I missing?

EDIT:

This is my `updateUser()` method where the `http.put` request is made:

```
updateUser(id: string, user: User) {
  // console.log('user ID is: ' + id);
  // console.log('User object passed to updateUser() is: ');
  // console.log(user);
  return this.http.put(this.baseUrl + 'user/' + id, user);

}
```

Which hits the `UpdateUser()` in the `UserController.cs` at the back-end.

Comment: If `User.FindFirst` returns a `null`, using `.Value` on it will throw. You haven't posted the actual requests, so one can only guess that the two requests are different. You can use eg Fiddler or your browser's Network tab in Developer tools to check what's actually being sent to the server. I suspect the Angular request is missing an authentication header or cookie so `UpdateUser` runs anonymously, which means there's no current User

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, Thank you for the comment and useful info, I think you may be onto something there. I will try to investigate this and will report back. Thanks again for taking the time to help out.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the information provided by [Panagiotis Kanavos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/134204/panagiotis-kanavos) I investigated it further and the request was missing the authentication header.

Because I am using `JwtModule`:

```
export function tokenGetter() {
   return localStorage.getItem('token');
}
```

```
 JwtModule.forRoot({
     config: {
        tokenGetter,
     }
  })
```

I thought that my token should be added to the headers automatically without having to add it manually.

The mistake I made was not including correct `whitelistedDomains` options inside the `JwtModule` configuration and that is why it was not added to the request header.

The solution was to whitelist the correct domains like this:

```
JwtModule.forRoot({
         config: {
            tokenGetter: tokenGetter,
            whitelistedDomains: ['localhost:5000', 'localhost:5001'],
            blacklistedRoutes: ['localhost:5000/auth']
         }
      })
```